# Поиск двух минимумов в массиве

Tags: python, массивы

В массиве хранится информация о количестве людей, живущих на каждом из 15 этажей дома (на первом этаже — в нулевом элементе массива, на втором — в первом и т. д.). Определить два этажа, на которых проживает меньше всего людей. (Если минимальное количество жителей одинаково на 2х и более этажах, то вывести наименьшие этажи )

Входные данные: Элементы массива вводятся в одну строку через пробел
Выходные данные: Вывести два числа в одной строке через пробел, сначала этаж с самым маленьким числом людей. При одинаковом количестве жителей - сначала наименьший этаж.

> Мой код, в котором я пузырьком сортирую и вывожу индексы 1 и 2
>   элемента отсортированного массива в изначальном, проходит 4 из 5
>   тестов => я что-то упустил, бьюсь уже несколько дней поэтому задаю
>   вопрос здесь

```
N = 15
a = input().split(' ')
a = [int(x) for x in a]
if a[0] > a[1]:
    mn1 = 0
    mn2 = 1
else:
    mn1 = 1
    mn2 = 0

for i in range(2,N):
    if a[i] < a[mn1]:
        b = mn1
        mn1 = i
        if a[b] < a[mn2]:
            mn2 = b
    elif a[i] < a[mn2]:
        mn2 = i
if mn1 < mn2:
    print(mn1+1, end = " ")
    print(mn2+1)
else:
    print(mn2+1,end=" ")
    print(mn1 + 1)
```

**Запрещенные операторы:sort;min;max;reverse;count**

Comment: Это и есть `Мой код, в котором я пузырьком сортирую и вывожу индексы 1 и 2 элемента отсортированного массива` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начало у вас почти верное (перепутали максимум и минимум) а вот сортировка не нужна

```
 N = 15
 a = input().split(' ')
 a = [int(x) for x in a]
 if a[0] > a[1]:
      mn1 = 1
      mn2 = 0
 else:
      mn1 = 0
      mn2 = 1

 for i in range(2,N):
    if a[i] < a[min1]:
        min2=min1
        min1=i
    else:
         if a[i] <a[min2]:
             min2=i

 print(min1+1, min2+1)
```